# How to bind the view to the VM wrapper instead of directly to the Model when multiple levels

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, mvvm-light

Say i have a Model structure like this

```
Being
|_ Person
   |_ Billing Address
   |_ Customer
      |_ Shipping Addresses (Collection)
      |_ etc..
   |_ etc..
```

My View is this

```
  ListBox (ItemsSource - bound to a VM wrapper of "Being")
    - DataTemplate containing ListBox2 (ItemsSource - bound to a VM wrapper of "Person")
       - DataTemplate containing ListBox3 (ItemsSource that I want to be bound to "Shipping Adresses") PROBLEM!
```

Im using MVVM Light and the Locator, but cannot figure out how to do the third level - the "Shipping Adresses" binding in the third second DataTemplate (ListBox3). It only allows me to bind to the Shipping Addresses Collection in the model directly. But I want to do it in a VM wrapper of Customer, because I need to do something with the collection. Any code will help for the inner binding.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your model hierarchy, it looks like Shipping address is the 4th level (unless you mean for Being to be abstract or zero). You should be able to dig into each Model's members like so

```
<Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding Being}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <Listbox ItemSource="{Binding Person}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Listbox ItemSource="{Binding Customer}">
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Listbox ItemSource="{Binding ShippingAddress}"/>              
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Listbox>                
            </DataTemplate>
        </Listbox>
    </DataTemplate>
</Listbox>
```

Additionally, I believe dot notation works in XAML on properties. So try something like this

```
<Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding Being}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <Listbox ItemSource="{Binding Person}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Listbox ItemSource="{Binding Customer.ShippingAddresses}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Listbox>
    </DataTemplate>
</Listbox>
```

If you could post some code snippets, I am sure a solution can be found!